# Remove one element from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to remove one element from javascript array. The element I want to remove is the value of 'NT'.   I have a HTML input

```
        <input type="text" id="caseType" size="50"/>
```

We populate it with

```
var caseTypeJson = jQuery.parseJSON('${crFilingCaseDetailForm.caseTypes}');
```

I want to remove one element from the javascript array

```
  jQuery(function () {

        jQuery.each(caseTypeJson, function (index, item) {
            if(("NT") == item.value){  // remove this element
                caseTypeJson.splice(index,1);
            }
            if (item.value == '${crFilingCaseDetailForm.selectedCase.caseType}') {
                jQuery('#caseType').val(item.value + ' - ' + item.description);
                jQuery('#selectedCaseType').val(item.value);
            }
        });

   });
```

This splice approach is not working. In doing some prior research I also tried the javascript delete too and that left the undefined element. Does this seem like a good way to do this?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: This question isn't clear. What does the HTML input control have to do with removing an element from an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using grep.

```
 var values = jQuery.grep(caseTypeJson, function(item) {
     if (("NT") != item.value) return item;
 });
```

This will give you an array without the NT value.

Comment: Thanks @vilecoder!  It worked great.  Sorry @Charlie Kilian I just through that in as a bonus... :)